# NuoDB - Where's the catch?

Tags: database-theory, distributed-databases, nuodb

I've been reading on the promise of an ACID compliant database management system without sacrificing horizontal scaling capabilities.

Where is the catch? Which part of the CAP theorem did they choose to sacrifice? Or did they develop some new database theory solution to be able to cover the whole spectrum?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Is there something in their architecture whitepaper that seems unclear?

Comment: `Which part of the CAP theorem did they choose to sacrifice?` This makes no sense - the very theorem states that you cannot have `C AND A AND P` at the same time (a sacrifice). What you have to ask is `Is the system AP or CP?` My take on NuoDB is that it is CP - this essentially means that in the event of network failures, the system will choose C over A. [This](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-relation-between-SQL-NoSQL-the-CAP-theorem-and-ACID), [this](https://martin.kleppmann.com/2015/05/11/please-stop-calling-databases-cp-or-ap.html) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NewSQL) help.

Comment: @Vérace I could have been more clear. But you have gotten my jist. Thanks for the links and you have already answered my question.

Comment: I can write this up as an answer if you like - expand obviously. I enjoyed delving a bit more into the topic and it might be nice for posterity... hell, I'll do it anyway - it'll be a learning experience for me - +1 to you for that :-)

Comment: @Vérace you gonna convert those comments to an answer or should I?

Comment: Hi - and thanks for the comment! You'll have to give me till (way!) later today - have a lot on! If you want to go for it using my quotes, be my guest! :-) Let me know if you have...